# How do I edit strings?

Tags: objective-c

How can I edit strings?

```
[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:];
```

I need a string to have a quotation mark,then a string called `self.quote.text` and then another quotation mark, then a dash, then a hyphon, and then a string called `self.quote.text`, and then another constant string. I have tried and tried but I can't figure out how to do it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"-_%@", self.quote.text, self.quote.text, self.quote.text]];`. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The key is the [`NSMutableString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.  It has a bunch of easy string creation and appending functions

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, what you want to do is create a string incorporating constant and variable elements.  You can do this with `NSString`'s class method `stringWithFormat:`.  For example:

```
NSString *resultingString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@'-%@constant", self.quote.text, self.quote.text];
```